# Using itemgetter instead of lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to put the following sort into using the `itemgetter` operator?

```
res = sorted(res, key = lambda x: (x['operation'], x['path']))
```

Previously I had `res.sort(key=itemgetter("path"))`, but I was having trouble figuring out how to sort in-place with multiple sorts.

Comment: `key=itemgetter("operation", "path")`

Comment: @DanielMesejo -- thanks, why don't you put that in an answer and I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: With all due respect, but you couldn’t figure this out from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)…?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = [{"operation": 1, "path": 2}, {"operation": 1, "path": 1}]

res = sorted(res, key=itemgetter("operation", "path"))

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'operation': 1, 'path': 1}, {'operation': 1, 'path': 2}]
```